# Prove or disprove that in any infinite list of graphs, some graph is a subdivision of another.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem**

Prove or disprove that in any infinite list of graphs, some graph is a subdivision of another.

**My idea**

The graph minor theorem was proved by Robertson and Seymour in 1985, but I wonder if there is some counterexample to the analogue of subdivision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be a subdivision (of anything other than itself) a graph must have at least one vertex of degree $2$. So for any infinite list of graphs without vertices of degree $2$, no graph is a subdivision of any other.

Answer (score 0):

What about the list of all the complete graphs?